# Pronoun it or them

Tags: pronouns

Q - Can I get the 16 digit card number?
A - Sure, hmm
Q - So can I have them?

My question here is that numbers are supposed to be a non-living thing and ideally it is what is used for non-living things. So shouldn't the answer be "So can I have it?"

Comment: It has nothing to do with living or non-living subjects, just the plurality of the subject itself. Use _them_ for plural subjects, and _it_ for a singular subject. In this case, though, I'd use _it_ because you're asking for _a_ 16-digit string off a card, which (though made of many digits) is a single thing.

Comment: I don't know what ***the** 16 digit card* refers to, but whatever ***it*** is could be established, and syntactically it's a single thing. Certainly if I say *I want **the** latest book by David Deutsch* I don't expect to be offered more than one copy. Although I suppose the [bibliothecary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bibliothecary) (sorry - couldn't resist! :) might produce hard- and softback copies for me to choose between.

Comment: Hi VampDuc, thank you for a swift reply. If someone to say " I have three books, that i took from you " Will the answer " Can i have them" be deemed correct. As per the previous explanation  it seems a "yes" but would u have something I could study more on.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "it" versus "them" as pronouns has nothing to do with living or non-living subjects.

Use "them" for plural subjects and "it" for singular subjects.

### Example

> There is a 16-digit code on your card. Please enter it into the box.

There is only one 16-digit code, which makes the subject singular, so you say "it," referring to the entire code.

> There are four 4-digit chunks on your card. Please enter them into the box.

There are four chunks, which makes the subject plural, so you say "them," referring to all the chunks.